# What dimension does the linear subspace $\text{span}\left\{v_{1},v_{2}\right\}+V$ have?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

> We are in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ and have the vectors
>
> $$v_{1}=\begin{pmatrix} 1\\  1\\  0  \end{pmatrix}, v_{2}=
> \begin{pmatrix} 1\\  0\\  1  \end{pmatrix}$$ and the linear subspace
>   $$V= \left\{\begin{pmatrix} a\\  b\\  c  \end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{3}:a-3b+c=0\right\}$$
>
> What dimension does the linear subspace $\text{span}\left\{v_{1},v_{2}\right\}+V$ have?

So $$\text{span}\left\{v_{1},v_{2}\right\}+V$$

This is equal to:

$$x\begin{pmatrix} 1\\  1\\  0  \end{pmatrix}+y\begin{pmatrix} 1\\  0\\  1  \end{pmatrix}+ \begin{pmatrix} a\\  b\\  c  \end{pmatrix}$$

I hope this is right so far? But what do I have to do with this so I know the dimension? Or did I write it wrong till here?

Comment: Now, what exactly do you mean when you say that the space is equal to $$
x\begin{pmatrix} 1\\  1\\  0  \end{pmatrix}+y\begin{pmatrix} 1\\  0\\  1  \end{pmatrix}+ \begin{pmatrix} a\\  b\\  c  \end{pmatrix}?
$$

Comment: Do you know this result: $\operatorname{dim}(A+B) = \operatorname{dim}(A) + \operatorname(B) - \operatorname{dim}(A \cap B)$, where $A$ and $B$ are subspaces of a finite dimensional vector space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $U$ and $W$ be subspaces of a vector space $V$, then 
$$\dim (U+W) = \dim U + \dim W - \dim (U \cap W).$$
Do you know this theorem? If not, then please let me know and I'll write out a proof for you here.

Now note that your $v_1$ and $v_2$ are linearly independent, so the span of these two vectors has dimension $2$.

And, the subspace $V$ also has dimension $2$; the vectors 
$$u_1 = \begin{pmatrix} 3\\ 1\\ 0 \end{pmatrix}, \ u_2 =  \begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 0 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix},$$
for example are two linarly independent vectors in $V$ and these two vectors span $V$, as you can check, I hope.

Now suppose that, for some scalars $\alpha_1, \alpha_2$, the vector $$\alpha_1 v_1 + \alpha_2 v_2 =  \begin{pmatrix} \alpha_1 + \alpha_2 \\ \alpha_1\\ \alpha_2 \end{pmatrix},$$ is in $V$. Then we must have 
$$ \left( \alpha_1 + \alpha_2 \right) -3 \alpha_1 + \alpha_2 = 0,$$ 
which implies that
$$ \alpha_1 = \alpha_2.$$
Thus, the intersection of $\text{span} \left\{ v_1, v_2 \right\}$ and $V$ is given by 
$$\left\{ \alpha \left( v_1 + v_2 \right) \ \colon \ \alpha \in \mathbb{R} \ \right\},$$
which is one-dimensional because $v_1 + v_2$ is not the zero vector.

Thus your subspace has dimension $$2+2-1 = 3,$$
and  so equals all of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Answer (score 2):

You can take a vector in $V$, for example
$$v_3 = \begin{pmatrix} 0\\1\\3\end{pmatrix} $$
and show that $\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ is a linearly independent set. So that span$\{v_1,v_2\}$ + $V$ = $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

$v_1\notin  V$ (nor $v_2$). What is the dimension of $V$? of $\mathbf R^3$?